# Why isn't android connecting to my web server

Tags: android, http, url

```
   package com.mohd.tryapp;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public static int flag;
    TextView view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);
        view=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textvi);
        getFlag var=new getFlag();
        var.execute();
        if(flag==1)
            view.setText("true");
        else
            view.setText("false");


    }
    class getFlag extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private Exception exception;


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try{
                String url="http://mohdgadi.netai.net/Register.php";
                int timeout=15*1000;
                URL myUrl = new URL(url);
                URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
                connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
                connection.connect();
                flag=1;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                flag=0;
            }

            return null;

        }

    }
}
```

So this is the code for my main activity i want to connect to my 000webhost website but the connection always shows false.I even tried changing the url to http://mohdgadi.netai.net/Register but that doesnt seem to work what might be the problem because of which the result is always showing false

Answer (score 2):

This is because, if you see the logs, you will notice that your code will throw a [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html). This means that Android doesn't allow you to make a Network call on the main thread. Therefore, move your code into an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception).

You should use `get()` to wait for the result to get populated, although it is preferred that you use `onPostExecute` to execute your code after `doInBackground` returns.

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);
        view=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textvi);
        getFlag var=new getFlag();
        var.execute();
        var.get();
        if(flag==1)
            view.setText("true");
        else
            view.setText("false");


    }
```

Comment: ok so I made changes to my code as u said look at my edited code but still its giving me false

Comment: This is because you are accessing the value before the flag is set. I have edited my answer, see it.

Comment: Still false why cant i connect :(

Comment: Have you included the `INTERNET` permission in manifest file?

Comment: yes i have included ,I need a favour can u write a simple code to connect to google.com given method above in asynctask

Comment: You can find an example at the android developer docs. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html